# Wkhtmltopdf failed (error code: -24). Message:

Tags: odoo, wkhtmltopdf, odoo-10

When I try to print preview the General Ledger report in ODOO 10, this warning message is popping up. Is there any fix for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It Seem like Your wkhtmltopdf version is not properly installed. Followed the step to install.

Downlaod this -https://downloads.wkhtmltopdf.org/0.12/0.12.1/wkhtmltox-0.12.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb

and then follow the step : (IF THE ABOUT WKHTMLTOPDF IS NOT INSTALL THAN AND THAN 1ST STEP HAVE TO DO IT) 1) sudo dpkg -i http://download.gna.org/wkhtmltopdf/0.12/0.12.1/wkhtmltox-0.12.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb

2) sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/bin 3) sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage /usr/bin

may be it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in an earlier post, you have incorrectly installed WKHTMLTOPDF.  You have to use the correct VERSION for your distribution or it will fail.

If you post which version of Linux you are using, perhaps someone will have the answer you are looking for.  Otherwise, this is discussed on the Odoo installation site: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/setup/install.html